# What is the CLI command to view inside of a set data type in redis

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I user a CRUDRepository in my spring data redis project to persist a redis hash in my redis cluster. i have rest api written to persist and get thte values of the data. this works fine.

however my entity annotated with RedisHash is being saved as a set / and i am not able to look inside the value using redis cli.

how do i look inside a set data type(without popping) in redis cli

i looked at redis commands page https://redis.io/commands#set 
i only get operations which can pop value . i neeed to simply peek

EDIT:
to make things clearer, i am using spring crudrepo to save  the user entity into redis data store. the user entity gets saved as a set data type.

when i query back the user details, i can see entire details of the user

{
userName: "somak",
userSurName: "dattta",
age: 23,
zipCode: "ah56h"
}

i essentially want to do the same using redis cli... but all i get is 
127.0.0.1:6379> smembers user
1) "somak"
how do i look inside the somak object.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/immem/core/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    @RequestMapping(path = "/save", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void saveUserDetails() {

        User user = new User();
        user.setAge(23);
        user.setUserName("somak");
        user.setUserSurName("dattta");
        user.setZipCode("ah56h");
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @RequestMapping(path="/get/{username}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public User getUserDetails(@PathVariable("username") String userName) {

        return userRepository.findById(userName).get();
    }
}




@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String>{

}



@RedisHash("user")
public class User {

    private @Id String userName;

    private @Indexed String userSurName;

    private @Indexed int age;

    private String zipCode;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserSurName() {
        return userSurName;
    }

    public void setUserSurName(String userSurName) {
        this.userSurName = userSurName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understant your descr with your problem, but I understand your title.

In redis set, the member is always string type.

I hope you can offer more info about UserRepository.save:

```
    User user = new User();
    user.setAge(23);
    user.setUserName("somak");
    user.setUserSurName("dattta");
    user.setZipCode("ah56h");
    userRepository.save(user);
```

And you can check your redis data and check data type when rest api invoked.

Comment: edited my question for more details and to make it clear

Comment: I think your data maybe not all in set struct.
I hope your can do in your test env:
- 1: exec flushdb command( flush redis )
- 2: invoke your api
- 3: exec keys *
- 4: exec type key_name(3 exec keys * get all key name)

Comment: 127.0.0.1:6379> type user
set

Comment: 127.0.0.1:6379> keys u*
1) "user:somak"
2) "user:userSurName:dattta"
3) "user:age:23"
4) "user"
5) "user:somak:idx"

Comment: i am not able to understand what exactly i am doing wrong?? the type of user is set bt the keys are coming as user:somak, user:userSurName

Comment: yes agreeed...its in hash structure 127.0.0.1:6379> hget user:somak age
"23"
127.0.0.1:6379> hget user:somak userName
"somak"
127.0.0.1:6379> hget user:somak zipCode
"ah56h"

Comment: @user1906450 I think you get and you know what is reason.